# should i be using any state management for api calls in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, flutter-dependencies

What is the point of using state management like provider or getx for apis ?

I mean why is the use of using any state management while it can be simply done with future or stream builder. Why do i need to use state management for crud operations of api like post,get,put,delete ?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Answer (score 0):

Usually state management solutions help you separate business logic from UI. This way you can create cleaner, more testable code  with separation of concerns and loose coupling.